# Limit passage in uniform continuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions

Let $f_n \to f$ converge uniformly on an interval $[a,b]$ and let $ \lim_{x \to a}f_n (x)$ exist for all $n$. Is it true that $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{n} \lim_{x \to a} f_n (x)\text{ ?}$$

Comment: It should be true, I feel.

Comment: I want to write it up as answer but I'm not completely certain, but yes it seems right. $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly and each limit exists as $x \rightarrow a$. So the sequence of limits $\{\lim_{x \to a} f_n (x)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ *must* converge to $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ (since $f_n \to f$ uniformly). That's how I'm seeing it.

Comment: It *might* not be true if the functions $f_n$ are not continuous. I believe the statement is true if $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly and the functions $f_n$ are all continuous. Otherwise, we can't be certain that $f$ will be continuous on $[a,b]$. But I could be wrong since $\lim_{x \to a}f_n (x)$ exists for each $n$.

Comment: Yes: see Baby Rudin (3rd ed.), p. 149.